# mysql insert and select rows with insert id

Tags: mysql, select, insert, innodb

I would like to select the first x rows say 10 before an insert. If there are no rows before the insert then it just returns the row that has been inserted

After an insert I am able to get the id by using 
       mysql_insert_id();

Is the an intelligent way to select the first 10 rows before this insert.

This must work for any number within the interval 0 or 10. So suppose they are 7 rows before the insert then it would just return 8 rows.

I was thinking of using limit like so

```
  $insertid  = mysql_insert_id()
  $postid    = 200
  Select a, b, c from mytable where a = '$postid' limit $insertid 10 order by b
```

but this doesn't work like I assumed.

Comment: Are you referring to the 10 rows inserted before this row?  The 10 rows based on some column id?  or something else?

Comment: No not the 10 rows inserted before this row. The 10 rows based on the variable $postid. I have edited my question

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY doesn't make much sense. In what sense are 'some' rows before 'other' rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select a, b, c from mytable where primary_key_col < '$insertid' and a = 200
ORDER BY primary_key_col DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I'm sorry I edited my question. Your answer would return all rows before the variable insertid but I'm trying to do this with only rows with column a as 200.

Comment: Updated based on your new requirements.

Comment: In order to select the inserted comment I used Select a, b, c from mytable where primary_key_col <= '$insertid' and a = 200
ORDER BY primary_key_col DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN :

```
Select a, b, c from mytable where a BETWEEN  $postid - 10 AND $postid
```

(the order matters)

Also, you should thing about using mysqli_ instead of mysql